# Link to bootstrap section id from button (not navbar)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap HTML page and I don't know how to link to a section of the page from a button.

My page has a navbar, which has the normal  in it.  Those links work just fine and will scroll down the page to the correct section.

If I create a button further down the page with something like:

```
          <div class="span4">
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-danger" href="#pricing">SEE PLANS AND PRICING</a>
          </div>
```

The button does not scroll to the part of the page.  It does nothing.

Any suggestions?

#### Edit 1

posting the html here: http://pastebin.com/M9y6NUei

Comment: can you show more code? Like the area that you want it to scroll too?

Comment: also please show the markup for the navbar

Comment: Ok, I posted a link to the slightly stripped down html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, your pricing button works well, after cleaning your messy code (missing closing tags, empty attributes...).

Here is working code: http://jsfiddle.net/s4LtE/

```
<div class="span4">
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-danger" href="#pricing">SEE PLANS AND PRICING</a>
</div>
…
<section class="" id="pricing" data-spy="pricing"
        data-target="#pricing">
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code could works when I mock it up.  The problem probably lies in other code.  Check to see if you have id="pricing" in the right place on your page and that it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured this out.  I had an "application.js" added that shouldn't have been.

My tips for other having issues like this on bootstrap.  Comment out all your javascript before asking your questions and see if that is causing your issues.

Thanks for all those who took a look at this for me!